# How are "DEFAULT PRIVILEGES" implemented in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, permissions

If I create a new `database cluster` (via initdb), then create a new `database`. How are the "default privileges" and "global default privileges" implemented?

For example, when I run `\ddp` in psql, it shows no rows. Does this mean  `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES` adds/removes rows in a table somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

information_schema is an ANSI-standard set of read-only views. You can easily learn what that views actual query are by reading the code which is [here](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/src/backend/catalog/information_schema.sql). The real catalog information is stored in [System Catalogs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalogs.html).

As [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-alterdefaultprivileges.html) says 'There is no ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES statement in the SQL standard.' So there shouldn't be anything related to information_schema.

Your records should be stored in [pg_default_acl](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-default-acl.html) which stores initial privileges to be assigned to newly created objects.

Comment: Thank you very much. That cleared up a number of questions and confusion I had.